# Proving even + even = even with mutual induction using tactics

Tags: coq

I was trying out mutual induction in Coq, the first type I defined was

```
Inductive IsEven : nat -> Prop :=
  | EvenO : IsEven O
  | EvenS n : IsOdd n -> IsEven (S n)
with IsOdd : nat -> Prop :=
  | OddS n : IsEven n -> IsOdd (S n).
```

I now wanted to prove that the sum of even numbers is even. I was able to do this using a Fixpoint and pattern matching:

```
Fixpoint even_plus_even (n m : nat) (evenn : IsEven n) (evenm : IsEven m) : IsEven (n + m) :=
match evenn with
  | EvenO => evenm
  | EvenS n' oddn' => EvenS (n' + m) (odd_plus_even n' m oddn' evenm)
end
with odd_plus_even (n m : nat) (oddn : IsOdd n) (evenm : IsEven m) : IsOdd (n + m) :=
match oddn with
  | OddS n' evenn' => OddS (n' + m) (even_plus_even n' m evenn' evenm)
end.
```

This defines both `even_plus_even` and `odd_plus_even`. I would now like to prove this using tactics in a more terse way (preferably without using many predefined lemmas to keep the code as self-contained as possible) but I haven't gotten very far.

Specifically, is it possible to prove both `even_plus_even` and `odd_plus_even` using only one Lemma like we can with the Fixpoint?

**Edit:** Thank you very much for your answers, the `Lemma ... with ...` syntax was exactly what I was looking for. In fact

```
Lemma even_plus_even2 (n m : nat) (evenn : IsEven n) (evenm : IsEven m) : IsEven (n + m)
  with odd_plus_even2 (n m : nat) (oddn : IsOdd n)   (evenm : IsEven m) : IsOdd  (n + m).
Proof.
  induction evenn; simpl. assumption. constructor. auto.
  induction oddn;  simpl.             constructor. auto.
Defined.
```

generates exactly the same proof term as the `Fixpoint` in my originial question.

Comment: TTBOMK you will stuck with using a tricky `fix` tactic, so your life won't be much better. My point of view, your are using the wrong Coq tool for your problem. Inductive definitions are extremely powerful theoretical tools, whereas `odd`/`even` are simple functions that are better defined as functions `nat -> bool` and even just `even n = ~ odd n`, as done in math-comp for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for instance prove both lemmas at the same time by "anding" them together into one lemma, and then extract the left or right part of the clause using `proj1` and `proj2`.

```
Lemma even_or_odd_plus_even:  forall (n m : nat),
    (forall (evenn : IsEven n) (evenm : IsEven m), IsEven (n + m)) /\
    (forall (oddn : IsOdd n) (evenm : IsEven m), IsOdd (n + m)).
Proof.
  induction n; split; intros;
    try destruct (IHn m) as [He Ho];
    try apply evenm;
    try inversion oddn;
    try inversion evenn;
    constructor; auto.
Qed.

Definition even_plus_even n m := proj1 (even_or_odd_plus_even n m).
Definition odd_plus_even n m := proj2 (even_or_odd_plus_even n m).
```

gives you

```
even_plus_even : forall n m : nat, IsEven n -> IsEven m -> IsEven (n + m)
odd_plus_even  : forall n m : nat, IsOdd n -> IsEven m -> IsOdd (n + m)
```

Notice that the two clauses share share the `n` and `m`, which you need if the clauses can't be proved separately because they need to depend on each other.  (In this particular case they don't, though. You *could* prove the statements separately, as Anton showed.)

EDIT: just saw Vinz solution. I didn't know Lemma had the `with` syntax (thanks for showing!), but that makes sense and is I think a neater way to do this mutually dependent definition.

```
Lemma even_plus_even: forall n m, IsEven n -> IsEven m -> IsEven (n+m)
 with odd_plus_even: forall n m, IsOdd n -> IsEven m -> IsOdd (n+m).
Proof.
  induction 1; simpl; auto using EvenS.
  induction 1; simpl; auto using OddS.
Qed.
```

Comment: Actually, both `Lemma` and `Fixpoint` are just aliases for `Theorem`, see [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#hevea_command20), which means that you can also define Fixpoint definitions with proof tactics, without giving the explicit proof term upfront.  By the way, the `refine` tactic is useful if you want to give parts of the proof term explicitly, while leaving holes to fill in by tactics.

Answer (score 5):

There is support for mutual induction in Coq. I know of two ways, but I only recall how to use one:

1. Combined Schemes

Here is how it works:

```
Scheme IsEven_ind2 := Induction for IsEven Sort Prop
  with IsOdd_ind2  := Induction for IsOdd Sort Prop.

Combined Scheme IsEvenOdd_ind from IsEven_ind2, IsOdd_ind2. 

Lemma foo: (forall (n: nat) (evenn: IsEven n), forall m (evenm: IsEven m), IsEven (n + m) ) /\
           (forall (n: nat) (oddn: IsOdd n), forall m (evenm: IsEven m), IsOdd (n + m)).
Proof.
apply IsEvenOdd_ind.
- now intros m hm.
- intros h hn hi m hm.
  rewrite plus_Sn_m.
  apply EvenS.
  now apply hi.
- intros h hn hi m hm.
  rewrite plus_Sn_m.
  apply OddS.
  now apply hi.
Qed.
```

2. `Lemma` `with`

On this one I just don't know how to finish it but that's a syntax issue iirc:

```
Lemma foo: forall (n m: nat) (evenn: IsEven n) (evenm: IsEven m), IsEven (n + m)
with bar:  forall (n m: nat) (oddn: IsOdd n) (evenm: IsEven m), IsOdd (n + m).
Proof.
- intros n m hn; revert m; induction hn as [ | p hp]; intros m hm; simpl in *.
  + exact hm.
  + now apply EvenS; apply bar.
- intros n m hn hm; revert n hn; induction hm as [ | p hp]; intros n hn; simpl in *.
  + now apply bar; [ exact hn | apply EvenO ].
  + apply bar; [ exact hn | ].
    now apply EvenS.
(* can't Qed, I get a Error: Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix. *)
Qed.
```

**Edit:**
Here is a valid syntax for the `Lemma with` solution.

```
Lemma foo (n: nat) (evenn: IsEven n): forall (m: nat) (evenm: IsEven m), IsEven (n + m)
 with bar (n: nat) (oddn:  IsOdd  n): forall (m: nat) (evenm: IsEven m), IsOdd  (n + m).
Proof.
- induction evenn as [ | p hp]; intros m hm; simpl in *.
  + exact hm.
  + now apply EvenS; apply bar.
- induction oddn as [p hp]; intros n hn; simpl in *.
  + apply OddS.
    now apply foo.
Qed.
```