# How to use a proof about a datatype within the same datatype definition in Coq?

Tags: coq, circular-dependency

I have the following Inductive datatype in Coq:

```
Inductive foo : ioh -> Type := 
| inp : nat -> nat -> foo Input
| out : nat -> nat -> string -> foo Output
| mat : foo Input -> foo Output -> foo Internal .
```

I want `mat` to additionally carry a proof about the relation of `foo Input` and `foo Output`, such that I want to change mat to somthing like this with `check i o` holding a proof over `i`and `o`:

```
| mat : forall (i : foo Input)(o : foo Output), check i o -> foo Internal.
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, as `Definition check (i : foo Input)(o : foo Output) := ...` needs to be aware of the datatype definition and the datatype definition needs to be aware of check. Thus, this gives a circular dependency. Is there a way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: You can use mutually inductive definition. Look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560581/proving-even-even-even-with-mutual-induction-using-tactics

Comment: I think it would help to tell us how you want to define check: as an inductive predicate? As a recursive function? As a simpler thing? This will have quite some impact on how to make this dependency work out…